# Is it correct to say "What's the best search tools in windows?"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I saw a question in superuser.com, and the title ran:

> What’s the fastest desktop search tools you’ve used on Windows?

It uses `'s` with `tools`, is this correct? Or should it be `What's the best tool` or `what're the best tools`?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, and I found myself more confused. -_-#

Answer (score 4):

*What are* should be used if it's formal. Informal occasions would accept *what're*.

Note that in AmEng at least, *is* is becoming the dominant inflection of *be* when used with existential *there* (i.e. *There's many ways to do that*), so I wouldn't be surprised to see this trend shift to any cases where the correct agreement must be found later in the sentence. AmEng is shifting to a preference for *sentence-initial* agreement rather than *syntactic-role* agreement.

Comment: I'm not sure it's common to write the contract "What're" (even though that's how it would usually be pronounced).

Comment: becoming more so every day: http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=what%27re&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: But compare "what are" with "what're" and you'll see that the latter is so comparatively rare that its instance count effectively appears as 0.

Comment: Because most texts are formal in style. That's changing however as most text 'published' in electronic form does not pass through an editorial team first, so the register of written language is changing rather rapidly.

Comment: It's not right to interpret common grammatical mistakes as being the "direction" in which the language is moving.  Grammatical mistakes in all European languages have been quite common, for centuries, but usually have given way to other mistakes, rather than being absorbed as a structure of the grammar.

Comment: I've given my evidence which convinces me that it's not just a grammatical mistake which will fade away. Where's yours?

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely right. This sentence has a mistake.
 He has already used "is" as the verb (What's), and so, the subject should be singular as well (*tool*, not *tools*) .
  Or, he could change the  verb as you did to plural (What're), and thus, keep "tools". Good point out.

This is called ["subject-verb agreement":](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

> The basic rule states that a singular subject takes a singular verb, while a plural subject takes a plural verb.

Thus, the example OP gave couldn't have been "What's the fastest... **tools**", because "What's" is actually "What is", and thus, the verb is singular, whereas, "tools", the subject" is a plural.

Comment: Reason, for downvote?

Comment: Sorry, was about to comment: my downvote is that I see no reason to say that the subject "should" be singular. In informal English, it's common to use "What's...?" with a plural subject. As far as I can see, the style of English is completely appropriate to its context; I see little reason for the "should" that you are positing.

Comment: I'm not talking in terms of the informality of this sentence, but rather on the *grammaticality* of the sentence. Thus, if considering the sentence grammatically, the subject and the verb *has* to agree in number.

Comment: Well, my judgement would be that "What's the tools...?" is grammatical. Why do you suppose that in order to be grammatical, a sentence has to be written in a formal variety of the language?

Comment: "What's the tools" is, in short, ungrammatical. Acceptable as informal, but ungrammatical. "What's" is short for "What is". In the face of the grammar rule of "subject-verb agreement", how can one say "what's the tools" is grammatical?

Comment: Descriptively, it's grammatical. I think it's misleading to say that it's ungrammatical, as this implies that it falls outside the scope of native speaker usage, which clearly isn't true.

Comment: Grammatical = following the accepted rules of grammar. `What's the tools...` does not follow the rules of English grammar.

Comment: @CJM - if you use that definition of "grammatical", just bear in mind it's not the one used by linguists...

Answer (score 0):

The sentence as it stands is grammatical. It is written in an informal register, but grammatical.

In a formal register, "What are..." would be used. But there's little reason to suppose that a question on an informal Internet forum "should" be written in a formal register: as far as I can see, the question as it stands is perfectly appropriate for its context.

I don't think people would commonly write "What're..." with a contraction, even though arguably that is a closer representation of the pronunciation than "What are" (similarly, people don't tend to write "Would've", but that's usually how it's pronounced).

Comment: I think you are confusing grammatical and informal. Writing in informal makes the sentence acceptable even when ungrammatical, but that doesn't make the sentence grammatical..

Comment: I agree with @Thursagen - the wikipedia article on register is vague, but surely your answer could apply to a lot of questions on this site? I'd have thought that the OP's sentence, like a lot of spoken language, is indeed grammatically incorrect, but that it's fine to use it informally.

Comment: I would argue that it's "grammatically incorrect" only in a prescriptive sense; descriptively, it's grammatical.

Comment: Can't you say that about all attempts to formally categorise grammer? If you define 'grammatical' to mean 'descriptive' then aren't you saying that all constructs used by people are by definition grammatical? In which case, as I said before, many questions on this site are moot. I'm not some kind of language purist, btw, just trying to get at how we define 'grammatical'...

Comment: How you actually define "grammatical" isn't trivial, but linguistis generally take it to mean something like: "generally judged to be well-formed by a native speaker", where "well-formed" isn't a value/preference/etiquette judgement, but simply a judgement as to whether the utterance is structurally within the bounds of one that a native speaker would produce. Now, there are problems with this, e.g. a sentence may be judged ungrammatical simply due to a failure of imagination (not being able to think of the context where a highly context-dependent utterance would be used)...

Comment: ...but I think the question in hand is reasonably unambiguously on the side of "grammatical" from the point of view of this definition. Put another way: if you label it "ungrammatical", then you would end up labelling a huge number of utterances readily produced by native speakers in everyday usage as also being "ungrammatical", and it's not clear to me that such a definition is descriptively very useful.

Comment: That's a fair enough definition but IMHO the point of most questions on this site is to tease out the differences between formal and informal usage, and using the test of 'would be said by a native speaker' to define grammatical isn't always enough, innit? :)

Comment: That's definitely one purpose and yes, it is impotrant for learners to gain a greater appreciation of register. That's why in my answer, for example, I explicitly explain that the difference between "What's the tools" and "What are the tools" is one of formality in this case. But just saying "it should be X" or "only X is grammatical", where X is specifically the variant used in formal usage or prescribed by a particular author doesn't really explain anything and could leave the reader more confused as to why we're saying it "should be X, not Y" when in reality what they see or hear is Y.

Comment: although I'm biased towards my answer, Neil's done a better job of explaining why in the comments. +1 @Neil

Comment: Informal registers or not, it is not grammatical - it does not conform to accepted rules of grammar, no matter understandable or commonly used you feel the phrase may be.

Comment: @CJM as I mention in my above comment, usually a linguist's definition of grammaticality doesn't have anything to do with "accepted rules", but rather whether an utterance is within the bounds of native speaker usage. Or put another way, grammaticality is more about saying that 'Cat on mat sat' is ungrammatical than about saying that "Many speakers object to using a singular verb with a plural subject", which is more a question of preference/etiquette than the structure of the language itself.

Comment: @CJM & Neil: it's probably apropos to distinguish between grammatical (proscriptive) and grammatical (descriptive). it seems that's the sticking point here.

Comment: Disagree completely. 

The lack of sub-verb agreement jolted me, and i had to re-read the sentence to see what was being communicated.

That's the very definition of "ungrammatical".

Further, i find it comical that you claim the sentence is "grammatical in an informal register", and then go on to decry the use of "what're", which is about as common a contraction in informal usage as one can get.  Just because it hasn't been adopted much into common writing doesn't make it any less valid a construct.

Comment: I like the 'jolted' remark - it reminds me of something I read about good punctuation being a form of good manners in that it enables the reader to smoothly parse the sentence. I think that the same applies to grammar and it also explains why these things are more important with the written word since a speaker's phrasing and tone of voice are not present to add clarity.

Comment: Kyle -- I'm not "decrying" the use of the contraction "what're" or expressing any value judgement about it at all. I'm merely saying, as a purely statistical observation, it doesn't appear to be as common as other contractions (i.e. if you look at % of instances of "what are" written as "what're", it's a much lower % than of e.g. "they are" vs "they're"). That said, I would still posit that there is a type of 'informal but edited' style of writing where "what're" may well be avoided, but not other more standard contractions. But I agree: that doesn't make it less "valid".

Comment: Are we going to start getting into prescripting *informal* writing styles now, too?